# package javax.xml.bind is declared in module java.xml.bind, which is not in the module graph | Cooja Ant Build

Tags: contiki

Help please !!!
This error appears while running ant on contiki simulator on kali linux[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOiHZ.png)

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. Also, I suggest that you use https://github.com/contiki-ng/contiki-ng/wiki/Docker - Cooja will work out of the box.

Comment: i tried what is described in the link you recommended to me but an other error appears, a screenshot of the error which appears to me is already joined to my post what other examples you want???

Answer (score 0):

The default Java installation on your system has deprecated javax.xml.bind.

The easiest thing to do is downgrade to jdk-8.
The best thing to do is fix the dependency problems in the build.xml.

Please see this issue for more detail:  https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/issues/2214